# How to wrap lines at window edge

Tags: default

My default line wrapping is 'truncate long lines'.

How can I change it to 'wrap line at window edge' ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Where have you looked?

Comment: The `truncate-lines` answer below is correct, but offers no additional bells/whistles.  You may also be interested in `visual-line-mode`, which sets the variable of `truncate-lines` and does some other things as well:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visual-Line-Mode.html

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that the default is to truncate long lines? This is controlled by the value of the variable `truncate-lines` whose default is `nil`. So by default any buffer *that does not modify that value* should be wrapped at window edge.

Check with `C-h v truncate-lines RET` to see what the default value is. Here for example is what I get in a `c-mode` buffer:

```
truncate-lines is a variable defined in ‘src/buffer.c’.
Its value is t
Original value was nil
Local in buffer foo; global value is nil
```

I suspect that you will find that the global value is nil in your case too.

The trouble is that a lot of modes do turn `truncate-lines` on, so AFAIK you have to play whack-a-mole with each mode whose behavior you want to change. E.g. for `fundamental` mode or `text` mode, you shouldn't have to do anything. But for
`org` mode, `c` mode, `python` mode and many others, the mode function explicitly changes the default value of `truncate-lines` to `t`.

Maybe there is a better way, but the standard way of undoing this is to add a function to the mode hook that will undo the change. E.g. for `python` mode, you have to do this:

```el
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'toggle-truncate-lines)
```

and you have to do that for *each* mode that turns `truncate-lines` on and you want it off.

That said, there are some good reasons to keep things as they are: e.g. for program files, you often keep them under source control and you use `ediff` to compare different versions: `truncate-lines` makes those diffs easier to read. Also, if you have lines that wrap, ask yourself why: text (ordinary as well as program text) is easier to read if you can take it in at a glance without having to move your eyes (or worse, your whole head) in order to get the whole expanse in: using shorter lines makes the `truncate-lines` setting moot.

See also the emacs documentation on `truncate-lines`, in particular this last bit:

> If a split window becomes too narrow, Emacs may automatically enable
> line truncation.  *Note Split Window::, for the variable
> ‘truncate-partial-width-windows’ which controls this.

You might find that leaving `truncate-lines` alone makes sense; and in the rare cases where it does not, use the menu to change it: click `Options/Line Wrapping in This Buffer/Wrap at Window Edge`. That will set it for the current buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.
My global setting is as follows:

(custom-set-variables
'(truncate-lines nil))

And in my org-mode truncate-lines as follows:

truncate-lines is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
Its value is t
Original value was nil

As you suggested I've added the following then it worked.

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'toggle-truncate-lines)
truncate-lines is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
Its value is t
Original value was nil

Thank you !

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).